# Regular expression matching various URL in an Angular proxy

Tags: angular, regex, proxy

In my Angular app, I have a proxy so I can bypass CORS issues with youtube videos.

This is my proxy:

```
{
    "\/api": {
      "target": "https://r1---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com",
      "secure": true,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^\/api": "/"
      }
    }
 }
```

My target is a youtube source videos I get from a python app in my backend. But every source beginning is the same except for this part:

```
"https://"xxxxxxxxxxx".googlevideo.com"
```

For exemple:

```
"https://r1---sn-25ge7jsl.googlevideo.com"
"https://r2---sn-25ge7ns4.googlevideo.com"
"https://r8---sn-25ge7nsl.googlevideo.com"
```

I think regular expression would help me have a single target that would match any other targets. I made some research and found that every matching charcaters is `/.*/`, how can I rewrite my target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
https:\/\/.+\.googlevideo\.com
```

The first part, `https:\/\/`, will find strings that start with `https://`. The backslashes are there to escape the forward slashes. Depending on which flavor of regex you use (I am not familiar with `Angular`), you may or may not need these backslashes.

The next part, `.+`, matches ***one or more*** instances of any character. If you replace the `+` with the greedy `*`, it will match ***zero or more*** instances of any character.

The last part of the pattern, `\.googlevideo\.com`, will match the strings that end with `.googlevideo.com`. Again, note the use of the backslashes to escape the use of the period. You need these backslashes here or this pattern will match an instance of any character, making something like this valid: `fgooglevideo5com`.

If you want to take this a step further, you could try something like this:

```
https:\/\/.{2}---.{2}-.{8}\.googlevideo\.com
```

The `.{2}---.{2}-.{8}` matches any two characters followed by three hyphens, followed by another two characters, followed by one hyphen, and then followed by eight characters.